# Error : file is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem where it says that a file is already being used by another process

But I am pretty sure it's not being used anywhere else..

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Browse
    Private Sub add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add.Click
        Dim Files As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim Folder As New FolderBrowserDialog
        Dim Filelist As String = "C:\Program Files\FTP-Sync\Files.txt"
        Dim FileP As String = ""
        Dim list() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Filelist)

        If fileb.Checked Then
            Try
                If System.IO.File.Exists(Filelist) = True And Files.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    FileP = Files.FileName
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

        If folderb.Checked Then
            Try
                If System.IO.File.Exists(Filelist) = True And Folder.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    FileP = Folder.SelectedPath
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
        pathtxt.Text = FileP
    End Sub

    Private Sub ok_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ok.Click
        Dim Filelist As String = "C:\Program Files\FTP-Sync\Files.txt"
        Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Filelist)
        Dim FileP As String = ""
        Try
            If pathtxt.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("No folder or file has been choosen")
            Else
                writer = File.AppendText(Filelist)
                writer.WriteLine(pathtxt.Text)
                pathtxt.Text = FileP
                writer.Close()
                Me.Hide()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub

    Private Sub cancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cancel.Click
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Browse_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry.. i do have a question, I cant see Where it´s wrong.. somewhere there is a error, but i cannot see where it is.

Comment: Use process explorer's handle search to see what process is holding onto the file.

Comment: And where sir do i do that ?

Comment: Additionally, there is a possibility that you're not closing your stream writer in your ok_Click method. Only if it hits the else condition will the stream close, otherwise the stream will be left unclosed. Consider changing from a try/catch to a using block `Using writer As New StreamWriter(FileList)`

Comment: `somewhere there is a error` is not very helpful

Comment: @xDaevax: i agree, this code seems to warrant some restructuring/refactoring/understanding of what happens :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of this:

```
Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Filelist)
```

i changed it to

```
Dim writer As StreamWriter
```

and it work like a charm.. dont know if it is the right way.. but it worked.

Comment: it is simply because File.AppendFile also opens the stream and returns the streamwriter object... Read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. So since you already locked your file (by creating new StreamWriter, the File.AppendFile threw the error)